# Why capacitors do not work when they are connected backwards?

Tags: electrical-engineering

As far as I know, capacitors have two metal plates and a dielectric between the plates inside them. So if they are just metal plates that are storing the electrical charge, why do they explode when I connect them backwards? If the plates are polarized how is this achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Non-polar capacitors are not polarity sensitive and don't explode when connected either way.

Electrolytic capacitors are polarised in their construction. Wikipedia's [Electrolytic capacitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolytic_capacitor) article has much to say on the subject that doesn't need to be repeated here.